# Close call does not release underlying resources for the device

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, filesystems, system-calls, tty

A bit of context: Linux 3.10.40, Multi-threads application, main thread waiting for user input (keyboard), other threads waiting (`epoll_wait()`) for events. No specific priority for either application or child threads, no bounding to a specific core.

I have a problem when I try to close the device */dev/ttyGS* from my application in user space. Close return 0 and file descriptor is indeed removed from the process fd list but the underlying tty port is not released (that because the `gs_close()` callback is not called).

It "only" happens when I test the following scenario: unloading my driver whereas the */dev/ttyGS* is still opened.
However, if I close */dev/ttyGS* during the "normal" application exit path, i.e. do the tear down sequence (including the `close(fd)` call) and exit the application, then unload the driver (in the shell) I am not facing this issue.

From my (main thread) application:

```c
// during application initialization
fd = open("/dev/ttyGS0", O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY)
fd1 = epoll_create(....);
epoll_ctl(fd1, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &evt);
fd2 = epoll_create(....)
....

// then during application life
system("rmmod mydriver");
  mydriver_exit
    // some code ....
    eventfd_signal
    // some code ....
    wait_event_interruptible

// Then from my event thread of my application
exit epoll_wait(fd2)
// some code ....
epoll_ctl(fd1, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, NULL);
close(fd)
  // .... some code within the kernel fs subsystem
  fput(filp);
    if (atomic_long_dec_and_test(&file->f_count)) {
      // some code ....
      if (likely(!in_interrupt() && !(task->flags & PF_KTHREAD))) {
        if (!task_work_add(task, &file->f_u.fu_rcuhead, true))
          return;
      // some code ....
      schedule_work(&delayed_fput_work);
      spin_unlock_irqrestore(&delayed_fput_lock, flags);
    }
// return from syscall
// some code ....
write(some_sysfs_attribute)
  // some code ....
  wake_up_interruptible
  // return from syscall
// some code ....
go_back_to_epoll_wait(fd2)

// etc...
```

Is that correct to call close from a child thread whereas the open was performed in another (the main) thread of my application? I guess so...

The problem I have here is that `file->f_count` is greater than 1, so the if branch is not taken and therefore the work, which eventually will triggered `tty_release()` and thus gs_write callback, is not scheduled.

I grepped the `f_count` increment location in the fs subsystem and and from the result I get, apart from open, there were in the locking subpart (i.e. /fs/lockd).

So I was wondering whether it could be some lock (involved by the `close()` call) that has a grasp on the file (increasing the reference count) during the close which could prevent the work from being scheduled (and thus the callback).

From what I know file descriptors are shared between all the thread of a process, and looking in /proc/<my_app_pid>/fd and /proc/<my_app_child_pid>/fd I indeed see the same fds.
Still if I am not mistaken I think the fd table is shared between all the threads (within the same process), which I guess might/should? involve some kind of lock which might explain the problem.

The thing is that I don't really know fs subsystem (neither architecture nor source code). I try to read the source but although some parts of it are understandable, others are less (or rather more tricky especially without a good overview). I am struggling a bit to identity what could have grasp on the reference count.

Any idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: You tested normal and abrupt ways to close fd in the app, but the abrupt way doesn't close properly? Since I don't have your code and don't have time to evaluate your full application, my assumption is there is something holding the resource, and you may make [mre] to check that.

Comment: A simple way is just grab related code you think it's related and try to reproduce the problem. That's the value of [mre]. Sometimes you may find the problem yourself.